# Why am I getting weird output within a foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

The statements that produced the strange output is

```
$response = '{"17366":{"title":"title1","content":"content1"},"22747":{"title":"title2","content":"content2"}}';
$result = json_decode($response, true);

foreach ($result as $document => $details) {
    echo "Title : {$details['title']}, ";
    echo "content : {$details['content']} ";
    echo '<br>';
}

//prints, this one ok
//Title : title1, content : content1 
//Title : title2, content : content2
```

But if

```
$response = '{"title":"title1"}';
$result = json_decode($response, true);

foreach ($result as $document => $details) {
    echo "Title : {$details['title']}, ";
    echo "content : {$details['content']} ";
    echo '<br>';
}

//prints
//Title : t, content : t
```

In this case, i know that the `$details` is not an array and it does not have such keys in it, if so it should have produced an exception or error. But it prints only the **first letter** of that string **for both**.

Anyone please points out what i'm doing wrong with those? or is that the behavior and i failed to assert something?

Comment: @PLB `string(83) "Cannot parse '"': Lexical error at line 1, column 2. Encountered: after : """`

Comment: It does look like the string constants, passed as keys are being interpreted as ints, or at least null values, that are then _"translated"_ to a `0`, giving you the first char of the string `Cannot parse...`, try echo-ing `'Second'.$details[1];`, too... see if that says `a`, and, if it does, set you ini to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $details contains a string and not an array, the key 'title' is casted to int. (int)'title' returns 0. $details[0] is 't'.

```
echo (int)'title';
```

Prints out 0

```
$string = "hello world";
echo $string['title'];
```

Prints out 'h'

```
$string = "hello world";
echo $string['1title'];
```

Prints out 'e' because (int)'1title' is casted to 1.

Answer (score 1):

It prints the first letter because it's trying to cast the associated key to a integer index.

So when PHP cast a string to integer usually return `0` unless the first character of the string it's a number.

By the other way as your code is trying to access to a string using indexes then PHP will return the Ncharacter of string specified by the index.

Mixing all:

```
$details = "title";

$details['content'] > $details[(int) 'content'] > $details[0]

$details[0] > "t"

$details[1] > "i"
```

Answer (score 0):

As details is a string if you use the [] syntax on it you select the character from the string at that positon. Selecting a character at position 'title' or 'details' doesn't actually produce an error, instead PHP handles it as though you are selecting the first character i.e. `$details[0]`.

Just add in a check to make sure details is an array:

```
if (is_array($details))
{
   // stuff here
}
```